# How do I keep mdadm from renaming my RAID array upon reboot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, software-raid, mdadm, ubuntu-11.10

So I have a system (a large instance running ubuntu-11.10 on Amazon EC2) where I've done something like

> mdadm --create bigdata --level 0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/xvdb /dev/xvdc

I get a RAID device of two disks (ephemeral instance stores) at `/dev/md/bigdata`. Yay. reboot. I now have a RAID device of two disks at `ip-10-811-498-737:bigdata`. (ip anonymized).

This is kind of obnoxious. I'd like to set up the RAID in a user-data install script, and set it up with a known device name, and then mount things from `/etc/fstab` - but the device name changes between creation and reboot, which makes this rather hard to pull off.

The `ip-10-811-498-737` is the hostname of the machine, and it seems to be the default for the `--homehost` option, so I know where that's coming from -- I just don't know how to keep it from showing up on reboot. (It's also the only RAID array that these machines will ever be exposed to ever, for that matter.)

Comment: any way you can share your user-data script that creates the raid array?  i've been at this for 3 days and still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `--name=bigdata` during creation.